# How to download CSV file through Firefox Profile in Java

Tags: java, csv, selenium, firefox, webdriver

Question - After Setting Firefox profile, Firefox keeps asking download location when downloading CSV file. Please help.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "..\\C_Automation\\Files\\geckodriver64_15.0.exe");
        FirefoxProfile Profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        Profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",downloadFilepath);
        Profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
        Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
        Profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
        Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv");
        Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(Profile);
```

Comment: Which version of Mozilla Firefox are you using? Can you confirm once the attribute is `helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` ? Can you help me with a snapshot please?

Comment: Firefox version is 52.0.2(64-bit). Dont know how to upload snapshot.

Comment: I have an Answer for your Question. But I need to test my Solution before I handover to you. So can I have the URL of the Website from where you are trying to download csv file? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any major issue in your code. But while you `setPreference` for the `FirefoxProfile` Class do remember to add all the relevant `Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions` of CSV type files referred in this [site](http://mimeapplication.net/).

Here is your own code block with some simple tweaks added to it:

```
String downloadFilepath = "C:\\Utility\\OP_Resources\\MozillaFirefoxDownload";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile Profile = new FirefoxProfile();
Profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",downloadFilepath);
Profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
//neverAsk - saveToDisk - CSV        
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values");
//neverAsk - saveToDisk - ANY       
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream");
Profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
//neverAsk - openFile - CSV
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values");
//neverAsk - openFile - ANY
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream");
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
```

I have verified my code on this [site](http://www.who.int/tb/country/data/download/en/) and Microsoft [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=45485) as well and seems to me works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your try but after adding everything what you suggested, firefox still opening open/save file window.

Comment: @TJ1985 Refer to my previous comment under your question `I have an Answer for your Question. But I need to test my Solution before I handover to you. So can I have the URL of the Website from where you are trying to download csv file?` Thanks

Comment: I wish i could give you but my client website is domain based so it wouldn't work in outsider laptop. If you r okay, i can work with you on decided time to share my screen and show you what i am getting. Please let me know your available time.

Comment: Can you quickly install Team Viewer v12 on your machine so we can work in tandem?

Comment: I know there is a issue while downloading from Microsoft sites, how about setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` & `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile` to each & ever type of file? Thanks

Comment: @TJ1985 Check my updated Answer, works for ANY site & ANY type of file. Thanks

Comment: I just added below code as you recommended but still no luck  Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", CSV);
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "ANY");
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","CSV");
Profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","ANY");

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH. FINALLY YOUR CODE WORKED. APPRECIATED YOUR TIME & EFFORT TO HELP ME. Since i am new to Stackoverflow, not sure how to recommend you. I will try to give points/recommendations for any users.

Comment: Is it possible to save default download location for IE11 browser so after clicking on download link, it doesn't ask any save file question ?