# Enable auto-download files to particular path in Firefox using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I want to download files automatically to particular folder using `Firefox(54.0.1 (32-bit))` and `Selenium`. Now I'm getting the download window each time, when I want to download a file(`.pdf`) and the path is always default(I want to customise it). What I have tried (`serenity.properties`):

```
browser.download.lastDir = C:\\Path\\To\\The\\File\\
browser.download.folderList = 2
browser.download.dir = C:\\Path\\To\\The\\File\\
download.prompt_for_download = false
browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = false
browser.download.manager.addToRecentDocs = true
browser.download.manager.useWindow = false
browser.download.useDownloadDir = true
browser.download.show_plugins_in_list = true
browser.download.animateNotifications = false
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile = text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf
browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force = false
pdfjs.disabled = true
plugin.scan.Acrobat = 99.0
plugin.scan.plid.all = false
plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types = application/pdf
pdfjs.enabledCache.state = false
```

For example in chrome it works for me with this settings(`serenity.properties`)

```
chrome_preferences.safebrowsing.enabled = true
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = C:\\Path\\To\\The\\File\\
chrome_preferences.profile_default_content_settings.popups = 0
```

PS I have tried already many suggestions from the Internet inclusive this site, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-download in firefox browser with java-selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/auto-download-in-firefox-browser-with-java-selenium-not-working)

Comment: @DebanjanB [Auto-download in firefox browser with java-selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/auto-download-in-firefox-browser-with-java-selenium-not-working) didn't solve my problem

Comment: Check this QA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074656/after-setting-firefox-profile-firefox-keeps-asking-download-location-when-downl/44084814#44084814

Comment: @DebanjanB [also no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074656/how-to-download-csv-file-through-firefox-profile-in-java/44084814#44084814)  . I have tried to download from another website something, to make sure that it doesn't depends on website I'm using. Download window appears and download path is by default.