# How To Fix File Download Error For Your Location With ChromeOptions in C# with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, mstest, chrome-options

**Background -** I'm trying to automate a website related to data restoring. So once the user logs in he/she can select the desired file/files and once the download button is  enabled the user is able to download the file.

**Problem -** I'm successfully able to download the file but the problem comes when I give my desired path where I want the file to be downloaded, I'm getting "`Failed - Download Error`" in Chrome on using ChromeOptions. I want to download the file inside my automation suite itself but currently any location that I try gives me same error.

*Please note - The location is already available and file type can be anything.*

**Code -**
Following options of code I have tried -

-- Options 1

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--browser.download.folderList=2");
options.AddArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.SaveToDisk=image/jpg");
options.AddArguments("--browser.download.dir="+@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\NewFolder\\");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\NewFolder\\");

localDriver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Downloads",options)
localDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

-- Options 2

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\NewFolder\\");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download","false");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking",true);

localDriver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Downloads",options)
localDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

-- Options 3

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--browser.download.folderList=2");
options.AddArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.SaveToDisk=image/jpg");
options.AddArguments("--browser.download.dir="+@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\NewFolder\\");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\NewFolder\\");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download","false");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking",true);

localDriver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Downloads",options)
localDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

**Questions That I Have Referred -**
[How to download CSV file through Firefox Profile in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074656/how-to-download-csv-file-through-firefox-profile-in-java)

[how to change file download location in Webdriver while using chrome driver/firefox driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire)

[C# Selenium ChromeOptions not setting/changing default download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429671/c-sharp-selenium-chromeoptions-not-setting-changing-default-download-location)

***Questions -***

1.) How can I ensure that file downloading is successful with ChromeOptions or FireFox Options.

2.) Is there any standard documentation for using chrome options in C#, because in many blogs these values are mentioned as string and in some it is boolean.

3.) Any other alternative approach for this problem which I can take to tackle this file downloading.

Comment: How is that related to MS Test? Why did you add the tag mstest? I don't see any MS Test related code.

Comment: Because this is a part of MS Test Framework, where I'm launching the browser. Do you want me to add the entire code apart from the problematic one ?

Answer (score 0):

For the solutions in C# we can use below code -

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreferences("download.default_directory",@"path_to_your_location");
options.AddUserProfilePreferences("download.prompt_for_download",false);
options.AddUserProfilePreferences("download.directory_upgrade",true);
```

Please Note :- Path_to_your_location must be complete, for e.g. you may be trying to refer to a location within your project but still use absolute path, for e.g. you may be referring to a location within your project like "`.\DataDownloaded`" but instead it should be `C:\Users\User1\MyProject\DataDownloaded`" then you would not get this error. Also please take care of the "`\`" and "`\\`" in  your paths, in this option only "`\`" works.